# How to divide an ellipse into two halves according to the center

Tags: python, opencv

I inserted an ellipse into the image, I know its center and I would like to add a line that divides the ellipse into two halves. This is my actuall code:

```
import cv2
import imutils

img = cv2.imread('labrador.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 100 , 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
cnt = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(cnt)
cv2.ellipse(img, ellipse, (0, 255, 0), 3)

x, y = ellipse[0]
cv2.circle(img, (int(x), int(y)), 10, (255, 255, 255), -1)

cv2.imshow("dog_with_ellipse", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Original image:

[image]

Original image with an ellipse

[image]

And result should look like:

[image]

How could I do that? And how to calculate the two points that could be used to divide an ellipse by length?

Add rotated labrador image:

[image]

Comment: the box version draws the ellipse thst inscribes the rotatedRect (box). The axis version uses width/height in an axis length manner, so it has to be only half of the size of the box in each direction

Comment: And what about angles?

Comment: should be the same for both versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way in Python/OpenCV. I note that the findEllipse() function returns the center, minor and major axes diameters and the angle.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

# read input
img = cv2.imread('labrador.jpg')

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 100 , 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# find largest contour
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# fit contour to ellipse and get ellipse center, minor and major diameters and angle in degree 
ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(big_contour)
(xc,yc),(d1,d2),angle = ellipse
print(xc,yc,d1,d1,angle)

# draw ellipse
result = img.copy()
cv2.ellipse(result, ellipse, (0, 255, 0), 3)

# draw circle at center
xc, yc = ellipse[0]
cv2.circle(result, (int(xc),int(yc)), 10, (255, 255, 255), -1)

# draw vertical line
# compute major radius
rmajor = max(d1,d2)/2
if angle > 90:
    angle = angle - 90
else:
    angle = angle + 90
print(angle)
xtop = xc + math.cos(math.radians(angle))*rmajor
ytop = yc + math.sin(math.radians(angle))*rmajor
xbot = xc + math.cos(math.radians(angle+180))*rmajor
ybot = yc + math.sin(math.radians(angle+180))*rmajor
cv2.line(result, (int(xtop),int(ytop)), (int(xbot),int(ybot)), (0, 0, 255), 3)

# save results   
cv2.imwrite("labrador_ellipse.jpg", result)

cv2.imshow("labrador_thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("labrador_ellipse", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

ADDITION:

For this image:

[image]

the code generates this result:

[image]

Comment: And what if the image is rotated? Result with your code: https://pasteboard.co/J5v2t3p.jpg

Comment: My computations involve the angle and so it should work for any rotation. In fact, your ellipse above is not perfectly vertical, it is at angle 179. You can see the slight tilt.

Comment: So, check the image pasteboard.co/J5v2t3p.jpg - it is incorrect, or no ?

Comment: How should I fix it?

Comment: OK. I corrected my equations for what I think are the proper rotations clockwise from the Y axis as 0 degrees. See my addition in my answer.